# Executable Not Available in ILDASM File Browser

Tags: .net, explorer, ildasm

When I navigate to `C:\Windows\System32`, I can see that it contains `Query.exe`

However, if I use `IL DASM` and go to the same location, `Query.exe` is missing along with a handful of other files, even though I have selected **Any Types** for the file types

At first I thought it might be because `query.exe` is not available to be decompiled, but I am able to see other `.exe`s in there which are also not available to be decompiled by `IL DASM` (e.g. `calc.exe`)

Why does `IL DASM` behave like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always beware the [file system redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx).  You are running the 32-bit version of ildasm.exe so it gets redirected to the home for 32-bit executables, c:\windows\syswow64.

A simple workaround is to navigate to c:\windows\sysnative instead.  Or to use the 64-bit version of ildasm.exe, say C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\x64\ildasm.exe.  Or to configure the Visual Studio Command Prompt (aka vcvarsall) if you use that, pass the "x64" argument.

Query.exe is not a .NET assembly so there isn't much to see.